# @font-face unable to generate "fonts that are in another server"

Tags: css, font-face

**I am working in a project that is a copy of google fonts!!
users will embed a code like this in their HTML code:**

```
<head>
<link href='hedayat-ei.ir/rest?fname=baran' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' >
</head>
```

**and take my server response:**

```
@font-face {
                font-family: 'baran';
                src: url('http://hedayat-ei.ir/rest/fonts/BBadr.eot?#') format('eot'),  /* IE6–8 */
                url('http://hedayat-ei.ir/rest/fonts/BBadr.woff') format('woff'),  /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
                url('http://hedayat-ei.ir/rest/fonts/BBadr.ttf') format('truetype');  /* Saf3—5, Chrome4+, FF3.5, Opera 10+ */
            }
```

but it doesn't work in online servers?
What's the problem?
all codes are good and it is tested in restconsole (google chrome plugin) and the response.
Is really the above code. but it doesn't work in real html pages.

**Is this because of .htaccess bad configuration?**
how can I solve it?
This is my final project in UV.

Comment: Can you give us the link of your website (and the structure of your webpage if you don't mind)?

Comment: Is this on all browsers? It could be a Cross Origin issue but I think Google Chrome would still render it fine

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is because you forgot to add .css to your href?

```
<head>
<link href='hedayat-ei.ir/rest?fname=baran.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' >
</head>
```